# Performance monitoring options in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-4.1, profiling, usage-statistics

I am developing a custom Content Management System in C# (SQL Server 2005) for my organization that operates primarily on Entity Framework 4.1. I would like some insight as to how my application is running, specifically when it comes to my EF queries.

What I'm looking for is a way to monitor the quantity, speed and actual execution (translated SQL) of queries being executed within a given period of time. Essentially I'd like to add DB profiling functionality into my application.

If at all possible I would to do this without implementing custom monitoring code for each one of my repository functions.

**My question is this:**
What is the simplest way to monitor in/out performance of the Entity Framework queries. I would like the following data:

1. A list of queries executed within the profiling time-span
2. For each query I would like to see execution time and actual SQL
3. If possible, the result size for each query would be helpful too

Comment: Can't you just use SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an existing tool, such as the Hibernating Rhinos [EF Profiler](http://efprof.com/).

Comment: I definitely can use an EF profiler but my preference would be to handle within this code so I can return the results through a web service.

Comment: @munroan - You can export profiler results and import into a DB or for use in a web service.